# MongoDB, Node.js "EventEmitter memory leak" in mongodb/server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, memory-leaks

I keep getting these EventEmitter memory leaks that originate from **mongodb/lib/server.js**. Althought I can find answers that will kinda "bandage" the problem by setting it to unlimited EventEmitters, I don't think that's the best answer for this situation because eventually my application will run out of memory. Whenever I change `self.s.server.setMaxListeners(50);` to a higher number, it always reaches that number.

Is there a way to go about this in the right way so that I can patch the memory leak caused by **server.js**?

**Stack-Trace/Error 1**

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 21 reconnect listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
at addListener (events.js:179:15)
at once (events.js:204:8)
at Server.connect (/Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:294:17)
at Db.open (/Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:196:19)
at userDB.findOne (/Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/lib/userDB.js:7:9)
at /Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/routes/index.js:200:12
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at /Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/express-session/index.js:433:7
at /Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:305:11
at handleCallback (/Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:12)
```

**Stack-Trace/Error 2**

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 21 destroy listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
at addListener (events.js:179:15)
at once (events.js:204:8)
at connectHandler (/Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:265:19)
at g (events.js:199:16)
at emit (events.js:107:17)
at /Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:388:23
at /Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:795:13
at Callbacks.emit (/Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:94:3)
at null.messageHandler (/Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:235:23)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/AriaDesigns/Desktop/Development/Liszt/version2/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:259:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)
```

This is where the problem happens inside **server.js**.
The first one happens at `self.s.server.on('close', errorHandler('close'));`

The second one happens at `self.s.server.on('reconnect', reconnectHandler);`.

```
// Connect handler
var connectHandler = function() {

// Clear out all the current handlers left over
  ["timeout", "error", "close"].forEach(function(e) {
    self.s.server.removeAllListeners(e);
  });

// Set up listeners
  self.s.server.once('timeout', errorHandler('timeout'));
  self.s.server.once('error', errorHandler('error'));
  self.s.server.on('close', errorHandler('close'));
// Only called on destroy
  self.s.server.once('destroy', destroyHandler);

// Emit open event
  self.emit('open', null, self);

// Return correctly
  try {
    callback(null, self);
  } catch(err) {
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
  }
}

// Set up listeners
var connectHandlers = {
  timeout: connectErrorHandler('timeout'),
  error: connectErrorHandler('error'),
  close: connectErrorHandler('close')
};

// Listbox Edits //
  self.s.server.setMaxListeners(20);

// Add the event handlers
  self.s.server.once('timeout', connectHandlers.timeout);
  self.s.server.once('error', connectHandlers.error);
  self.s.server.once('close', connectHandlers.close);
  self.s.server.once('connect', connectHandler);
// Reconnect server
  self.s.server.on('reconnect', reconnectHandler);

// Start connection
  self.s.server.connect(_options);
```

Since this is happening INSIDE the mongodb module, I'm having issues troubleshooting it or even knowing how to go about it.

**EDIT**

This is an example of how I use the server.js file

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'),  
Server = mongo.Server,
Db = mongo.Db;

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {  
  auto_reconnect: true
});

var userDB = new Db('listbox', server); 

userDB.update = function(query, item, callback){

    userDB.open(function(err, db){
        if (err) throw err;
        db.collection('usercollection', function (err, collection){
          if (err) throw err;

          collection.update(query, item, function(err,doc) {

            if (err) throw err;
            if (callback) callback(null, doc);
            db.close();

          })
        })
   })
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the greater scope of how this code is called or run, but it is clear the two delegates you are having issue with are "on" events and not "once" events. This leads me to think it may be related to delegates being added repeatedly or never being released.

Comment: I added to my question the scope in which I use it.I call the `userDB.update()` function whenever I want to toggle an attribute in a mongoDB object from "True" to "False" and vice versa. If I toggle it around 4 times, it will cause the warning to occur with the default 10 Event Emitters, 8 times with 20 Event Emitters, etc.

In response to what you thought about the "on" events, I figured that might've been the case too, so I changed the "on" events to "once" events but it still caused the problem to occur on the same exact lines!

Comment: Again I'm just throwing ideas out there. Could there be some type of recursion occurring or could you have other code somewhere else that ultimately prevents the release of these delegates?